# How to upload multiple files to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I currently need to be able to allow a user to upload a file to Jenkins for the job to then use.

I understand that the File parameter can allow me to do so, but how about if the user needs to add 100 files?

Is there a way to either:

1. Allow multiple files to be uploaded at once?
2. Upload a folder instead and then use my script to loop through the folder?

As a side note, the filenames need to have the same name as they had before they are uploaded too. When uploading one file via the File parameter, I could work around fixing that. With 100 files, maybe less so...

Comment: Jenkins is not a repository to which files are uploaded.

Comment: I don't want it to be stored there permanently. I want the user to be able to upload an artifact from their local workstation to the job so that it can transfer it to where it needs to be. Something like the File parameter... however I want it for multiple files.

Comment: Upload a zip file, then unzip it as a first step of your build.

Comment: There's an open issue for this exactly: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20527 . You can vote for it there.